# Getting error while write test case for render in Mocha

Tags: meteor, mocha.js, meteor-blaze

I have an Meteor project using BlazeJS. I am writing test case for that project in Mocha for rendering. And i am facing below error:-

`Error: No such function: _
  at blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3214
  at Spacebars.call (spacebars.js?hash=ebf9381e7fc625d41acb0df14995b7614360858a:172)
  at Spacebars.mustacheImpl (spacebars.js?hash=ebf9381e7fc625d41acb0df14995b7614360858a:106)
  at Object.Spacebars.mustache (spacebars.js?hash=ebf9381e7fc625d41acb0df14995b7614360858a:110)
  at Blaze.View._render (app.js?hash=5f5e88169d987fce5c1c7e49f67c237d33b43cb9:514)
  at Blaze.View.doRender (blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2086)
  at blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1934
  at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3744)
  at blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1932
  at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2271)`

Please advise how I resolved above error.

Comment: Can you please add the code of your `.tests.js` file? It seems to be related to underscore, which should be a core part of meteor. But in order to understand your problem, we need some more code.

Comment: Hi @Jankapunkt, thanks for responding and i have resolved the error by importing language json file in template js file.

Comment: Okay cool! Can you please anyway either add code that shows how you solved the problem?

Comment: Hi @Jankapunkt, i just imported language file in parent template :-
**import '/core/lib/i18n/en.i18n.json';**